# How to serialize Dictionary into base64

Tags: c#

I need to serialize the `headers` object to store it in string format, probably base64.
The `Dictionary<String, Object>` will only have String or Int values, so there should be no problem.

```
 Dictionary<String, Object> headers = RequestHeaders.ProcessHeaders(HttpContext.Current);
```

Also, of course the point is to be able to deserialize the base64 string back to Dictionary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't serialize a `Dictionary` into XML, but you could serialize it into JSON:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary, Formatting.None);
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

To deserialize:

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
Dictionary<string, object> deserializedDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

Comment: Where did I write that I want to serialize into XML?

Comment: Also, of course the point is to be able to deserialize the base64 string back to Dictionary.

Comment: Nowhere, but it is a common enough problem that I thought it worth mentioning. Is there any particular format you would like to serialize to?

Comment: Thanks! This is a very good answer, not sure why other users are saying that this cannot be done.

Comment: @user1662812, most people think as soon as you say "Serialize", you want your data in XML format. As stated, .NET does not support serialization of dictionaries into XML out of the box, hence the reason they say it can't be done...Anything can be done if you apply enough knowledge to it!

Comment: @NickW, isn't JsonConvert part of the JSON.NET API?

Comment: @NickW, I just thought it was worth mentioning that's all, otherwise the OP may try to implement the code above, looking for JsonConvert in .NET without realising it's a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly can I clarify that you cannot Serialize from Dictionary to Base64, because Dictionary is a structure, Base64 is an encoding format.

You need to serialize from Dictionary to XML (not supported by .NET but you can build your own serializer/deserializer for this, or use a 3rd party one), or JSON, or even Binary if it does not need to be human readable. Then, you can encode the result of the serialization to Base64.

ASP.NET ViewStates work similar to this (however I don't think a ViewState is a dictionary), but it is a structure which is serialized and then Base64 encoded.